# Exclude identical rows of 2 Dataframes R

Tags: r, dataframe, twitter

I have 2 Dataframes, containing Tweets about df1 = sons, df = daughters. 
While analysing i happened to notice, that some rows must be identical.

alltogether <- unique(rbind(df1, df2)) showed that there are indeed 587 rows identical (by subtracting it from df1+df2) 
How can in identify them? Or, even more important: exclude them from both dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

I think `duplicated()` is what you're looking for.

```
df <- data.frame(1, c("A", "A", "B", "B"), c("A", "A", "B", "B"));
colnames(df) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
df
df[!duplicated(df),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a column to each dataframe that stores information about the dataframe name. E.g. `df1$origin <- "df1"`. You can then `rbind` the dataframes.

You can then use `duplicated` to identify duplicated rows on the combined dataframe (excluding the origin column). The found indices can then be removed and the remaining dataframe can be split on the `origin` column into the original parts.